# CMake - develop for Windows and Linux at the same time

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I'm developing a small game in C++ and SDL for a contest for linux, but prefer to develop on windows.  Is there a tutorial somewhere that will show me how I can set CMake up so that I can somewhat easily have the code in SVN, pull a copy to windows, and use Visual Studio to edit it/update it/compile it, and at the same time pull a copy to linux and build it right there.

Comment: Post edited.  Its a contest for games that can run on linux, but I prefer to develop on windows with Visual Studio

Comment: How could you possibly prefer to code in windows? You'll probably have a fairly difficult time getting decent windows environment to build for linux. I'd recommend you download KDevelop on your linux machine, and never look back to windows.

Comment: @Falmarri: The decent windows environment to build is MSVC express, because his code is cross-platform.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't tried to research the subject yourself. CMake has tutorials, for example. What have you already tried?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmake%5D+cross+platform`

Answer (score 1):

Since telling you to google it is a pointless answer.....

cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" c:\source

to create VS project file which you can load in VS and build in command line with

msbuild Project.sln

In Linux:

cmake /source

and "make" to build